# Cannot get the image position in the body from Outlook Python API

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, office-automation, inline-attachments

I need some help, I am currently trying to do some scripting to automatize some tasks. I would like to fetch the received mail and send the body somewhere.

For that I am using **win32.com** with the **outlook API**.

But the issue is that if there is image in the body of the mail. I can't fetch it with the initial body. I Thought about using attachment, which is working but in the end, I have images and the body. But in the body I don't have the image position information... So I can only send the images and cannot set them correctly. Which can be difficult to understand if there is a lot of images...

So far the code looks like something like this :

```
import os
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')

mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items
message = messages[len(messages) - 1]

body = message.body

attachments = message.attachments
attachment = attachments[0]

file_name = attachment.filename

path = "D:\\Documents\\tmp"
attachment.SaveAsFile(path + os.sep + attachment.FileName)
```

Do you have any help on this ?
Thanks for your help :)

PS : Do you know where I can find the Python documentation for outlook API, I just find the Rest API one and there is some difference from both. Or if we can get the source code to check directly.

Answer (score 0):

In the message body you may check for `<img/>` tags. If any of them contains this tag with a file name prefixed with `cid:` string, for example:

```
<img src=cid:Filename/>
```

Then you deal with an embedded image which can be found in attached files.

Also you may check the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property on the attached files in the following way:

```
Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"

Function IsEmbedded(Att As Attachment) As Boolean
    Dim PropAccessor As PropertyAccessor
    Set PropAccessor = Att.PropertyAccessor
    IsEmbedded = (PropAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID) <> "")
End Function
```

The [PropertyAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor) can help you to deal with low-level MAPI properties in Outlook.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no <img/> tag in the body :/
```body = message.body 
#body ='My Image is :\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nEnd of image\r\n'```

I just have \r\n instead of my image.

Comment: Use the `HTMLBody` property instead.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use something like getHtml but it didn't work out. With the htmlBody I might be able to get what I want !
Thank you :)

Comment: See [MailItem.HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody)